# editable combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I have to create an editable combobox. The combobox contains name, age and city. The user can enter either name, age or city. The combobox has to filter all the list contain and should show relative list.

Eg:

```
Combobox contains  : xxx 23 ny, yyy 24 London, zzz 25 delhi, uuu 25 columbo.
Here user enter 25 : combo box has to show zzz and uuu rec
```

Comment: you will need to provide more information if you want some help. For instance, what language/platform are you using?

Comment: using jquery or using normal javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [JQuery's autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) ([demo and updated docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)) widget.

Check out the [combo box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) example

Answer (score 0):

This [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/comboboxtemplate) might help. It turns a regular `<select>` into a combobox, and when you type it filters the items that you see.