# Writable Select Box

Tags: jquery, html, select, input

Looking for a Jquery plugin so I can have a select box that includes a writable option. So using javascript to merge a select box with an input field. I'm thinking this would be a fairly common requirement, Anyone know of such a plugin?

Thanks

Comment: the common term (or at least the one i always see used)  is "Filtering Select". you might want to google for that. ive never seen anything for this with jquery but Dojo has it built in to its dijit form library and i think yui has one as well.

Comment: @prodigitalson Filtering Select is for narrowing down the options within the Select.  The question is for allowing an option that does not appear in the listed options.

Comment: Seems like you could put a text box in the same spot as the <select>. Then you'd bind event handlers for "focus" and "keydown" to juggle which one is on top.

Answer (score 6):

It will not be possible using SELECT instead I use the [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for '*editable comboBox*' or somewhere it is selectBox or maybe dropDownList, but everything is common name for something like this:

[image]

This is the best editable combo Box I've ever worked with: [jQuery Editable Combobox (jEC)](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jec/) and you can check [some demos](http://stuff.rajchel.pl/jec/demos/).

And if you would like to read something more about this problems, you could [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264640/how-can-i-create-an-editable-dropdownlist-in-html) [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945003/anyone-know-of-a-decent-editable-combo-box-plugin) [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496823/how-can-i-create-an-editable-combobox) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995225/editable-combo-box) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990697/jquery-custom-select-combobox) here on stackoverflow.com

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[This JQuery Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-autocomplete) may provide all the functionality that you need.

I am unsure if it  provides a user-expandable structure, however.