# Jquery autocomplete "search" method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI autocomplete, this is the code below

```
var opt_source = {...}
var options = {
            minLength: 0,
            source: opt_source,
            search: "aPreDefinedString"
        };
$(".searchable_input").autocomplete(options);
```

My  [understanding](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-search)  is that it should now search for `aPreDefinedString` ; This doesn't happen, rather it searches the local source for `userInput`. Could someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: are you using the jQuery UI library for anything other than autocomplete?

Comment: @jondavidjohn, tabs,a few animations.

Comment: ok, good, a lot of times I see people utilizing the entire UI lib, and only use a feature that could be had through third party plugin.  Was going to point you at one, but looks like you're utilizing UI.

Answer (score 7):

**OK, this is how I had to make it work**

```
var opt_source = {..};

var options = {
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response){
                response(opt_source);
            }
        };
$(".searchable_input").autocomplete(options);
```

This seems to override the inbuilt search (I hope they dont break it in future versions)

From the Jquery UI documentation

*The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:*

*A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the user entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain the data to suggest to the user.*

*This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with label/value/both properties). It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state*

Comment: +1: This is a reasonable way of doing it, and jQueryUI doesn't seem to radically change api functionality so I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Sorry for not catching your comment until just now, but +1 for working it out :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you're mixing up the [`search` ***event***](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-search) and the [`search` ***method***](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-search) on the `autocomplete` widget.  You can specify an event handler for the `search` *event* in the `options` object (which you're doing) that's used to initialize the widget.

The way you would call the `search` *method* is like this:

```
$(".searchable_input").autocomplete( "search" , "aPreDefinedString" );
```

This would manually search the autocomplete.

Comment: Indeed. While you were typing this, I was preparing this: http://jsfiddle.net/D2KJW/

Comment: Thanks, making *some* progress. I can now search my string for the initial keystroke, though it reverts back to userInput for subsequent strokes. @karim, could you complete the fiddle?

Comment: @RisingSun: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to force the search to always search for the same string no matter what the user types?

Comment: Yes. But the string is set programmatically, depending upon other user input. I expect between 1 - 7 options; a selectbox is not a option (the final user input is left to him/her).. *in short a combobox without the button*

Comment: @RisingSun: In that case, you'll need to leverage the `search` event to cancel the default search behavior and provide your own based on the input.

Answer (score 0):

my code is like this and it work.

```
var availableTags = ['aa','bb','cc'];

$( "#filterinput" ).autocomplete({
                      source: availableTags,
                      autoFocus: true,
                    });

$( "#filterinput" ).on( "autocompletesearch", function( event, ui ) {
                      console.log($(this).val());
                    } );
```