# Jquery autocomplete “search” method with "" parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created dropdown autocomplete based on jq autocomplete. 
So I want to get all values with empty textbox value.

I call this code:

```
element.autocomplete("search", element.val());
```

Where element.val() returns "".

And nothing happens. No ajax queries.

What should I do to send ajax query with value "" to server using jquery ui autocomplete API?

Edited. It connected to the exist post - [Jquery autocomplete "search" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776754/jquery-autocomplete-search-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the autocomplete drop-down to populate even when there is no content in the textbox. To do this, you have to have the `minLength` option set to 0. Once you do that, to have the search window open on command (as opposed to when the user types something then erases it), your javascript of `element.autocomplete("search", element.val())` should work.